In Mac I have downloaded Ubuntu and UTM after that i selected running option and it shows error like -
QEMU error: QEMU exited from an error: qemu-aarch64-softmmu: -drive if=none,media=cdrom,id=driveCFB16095-F43A-4E6D-AAE3-1363174ABF27,file=/Users/afreen/Downloads/ubuntu-24.04-live-server-arm64-2.iso,readonly=on: Failed to lock byte 100
I haven't try anything yet..I'm just fixing the error..but it's not happening from my end
